# How does CPU Credit consumption rate is calculated on AWS T2/T3 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can someone explain simply how are CPU credits consumed, i.e. at which rate on T2/T3 instances. 
I've been going through [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/unlimited-mode-examples.html) but I could not understand how, in the first example, phase 3, the consumption gets calculated

*P3 – For the next 24 hours, CPU utilization is at 7% (above the baseline), which requires a spend of 57.6 credits_. The instance spends more credits than it earns, and the CPUCreditBalance value reduces to 86.4 credits.*

How is 57.3 calculated ?

Answer (score 2):

### Background

Here is the basic info for the T3.nano instance referenced in the example:

```
Name                        t3.nano 
vCPUs                       2
Baseline Performance/vCPU   5%
CPU Credits earned/hr       6
```

(*see* https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/)

The broader concept of credit use in burstable instance is this. If you start a new T3.nano instance and run at exactly the 5% usage baseline stated above, you will have 0 credits at the end of 1 hour. If you run at 0% usage, you will have 6 credits earned at the end of 1 hour. At the end of 24 hours of 0% usage, you would have 6 * 24 = 144 credits.

### Answer

- Divide 7% usage over the 5% baseline for a T3.nano. This shows you're running at 140% of the baseline. (*i.e.* 0.07/0.05 = 1.4)
- Over a 24 hour period, the t3.nano earns 144 credits (*i.e.* 6 credits per hour * 24  hours = 144 credits)
- Running at 140% of the baseline for 24 hours, you would use 201.6 credits (*i.e.* 144 * 1.4 = 201.6)
- Take the 201.6 credits you used, and subtract the 144 credits you earned over the course of the 24 hour period, and you get 57.6 of credit burn beyond your earnings. (*i.e.* 201.6 - 144 = 57.6)

Comment: 144 being the CPU credits earned per hour for that T3.nano instance. 6 credits per hours times 24 hours equals 144 credits

Comment: Don't add information in comments, edit your answer.